# OData filtering with dynamic property of Date

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-4.5

I have created an EntityType called Document which contains dynamic properties:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

My DocumentsController returns a list of a single Document which has three different dynamic properties of types DateTime, int, and string.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(_documents.AsQueryable());
}

private List<Document> _documents = new List<Document>
{
    new Document
    {
        Id = 1,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "DynamicDate", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1) },
            { "DynamicInt", 10 },
            { "DynamicString", "abc" },
        }
    }
};
```

When I query the API with `/odata/Documents?$filter=CreatedAt gt 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z` the filter works as expected. Filtering the other dynamic properties with `$filter=DynamicInt gt 9` and `$filter=DynamicString gt 'aaa'` also turns out the way I would assume.

When I try to use `$filter=DynamicDate gt 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z` however, the following exception is thrown:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=full'.",
      "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
      "stacktrace": "",
      "internalexception": {
        "message": "Specified cast is not valid.",
        "type": "System.InvalidCastException",
        "stacktrace": "   at lambda_method(Closure , Document )\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simply retrieving a Document from the API with full metadata yields:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost:58245/odata/$metadata#Documents",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#DocumentArchive.API.Models.Document",
      "@odata.id": "http://localhost:58245/odata/Documents(1)",
      "@odata.editLink": "http://localhost:58245/odata/Documents(1)",
      "Id": 1,
      "CreatedAt@odata.type": "#DateTimeOffset",
      "CreatedAt": "2016-12-15T14:53:01.9903785+01:00",
      "DynamicDate@odata.type": "#DateTimeOffset",
      "DynamicDate": "2017-01-15T14:53:01.9903785+01:00",
      "DynamicInt": 10,
      "DynamicString": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I go about filtering a dynamic property that is a date?

I am using: Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.9.1